# Add custom property to vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I set a custom property inside a vue component?

```
var myComponent = Vue.extend({
    data: function() {
        return {
            item: {}
        }
    },

    created: function() {
        // This does not seem to work
        this.item.customProperty = 'customProperty';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set) to add reactivity:

```
var myComponent = Vue.extend({
    data: function() {
        return {
            item: {}
        }
    },

    created: function() {
        Vue.set(this.item, 'customProperty', 'customProperty');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you should use Object.assign:

```
var myComponent = Vue.extend({
    data: function() {
        return {
            item: {}
        }
    },

    created: function() {
        // This does not seem to work
        this.item = Object.assign(this.item, {customProperty:'customProperty'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This adds the property, but unfortunately does not add reactive getter and setter methods. Is there a way to do that?